# Robocopy log file - bad formatting

Tags: logging, format, robocopy

On: **[windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10)** Pro x64 and **`Robocopy.exe`** 10.0.17763.1

Batch .bat file runs Robocopy to backup my user direrctory on **`C:`** to **`H:`**

**`C:`** is SSD formatted **`HTFS`**,  **`H:`** is HD formatted **`HTFS`**

Command in the batch job is

```
Robocopy.exe "C:\Users\me" "H:\My Backups\RoboCopyBackup\backup" /MIR /XA:SH  /XD $RECYCLE.BIN "System Volume Information" AppData /XJD /R:2 /W:2 /MT:8 /V /NP /ETA /LOG:Backup-2020-05-22.log
```

The log file is partly ok.  Most lines look good - like :

```
same  3232 C:\Users\me\Documents\go\src\github.com\go-delve\delve\vendor\golang.org\x\crypto\ssh\terminal\util_solaris.go
same  3105 C:\Users\me\Documents\go\src\github.com\go-delve\delve\vendor\golang.org\x\crypto\ssh\terminal\util_windows.go
same 12216 C:\Users\me\Documents\go\src\github.com\go-delve\delve\vendor\golang.org\x\tools\go\packages\doc.go
```

So, line after line of status `fsize fname`

But many lines are garbled so:

```
same  fsize 
<blank line>
<blank line>
fname same 
fsize same fsize fname
same fsize same fsize
fname same fsize fname 
same fsize fname (back to normal)
```

literally

```
same 12216 C:\Users\me\Documents\go\src\github.com\go-delve\delve\vendor\golang.org\x\tools\go\packages\doc.go
same  5464 C:\Users\me\Documents\go\src\github.com\go-delve\delve\vendor\golang.org\x\tools\internal\fastwalk\fastwalk.go
same  8714   
same  6276 C:\Users\me\Documents\go\src\github.com\go-delve\delve\vendor\golang.org\x\tools\internal\semver\semver.go
same  1938    
same 24852 C:\Users\me\Documents\go\src\github.com\go-delve\delve\vendor\golang.org\x\tools\go\packages\external.go
same  1379 C:\Users\me\Documents\go\src\github.com\rogpeppe\godef\vendor\golang.org\x\tools\go\packages\visit.go
same 21314 C:\Users\me\Documents\go\src\github.com\go-delve\delve\vendor\golang.org\x\tools\go\packages\golist.go
```

Other rows are:

```
same fsize same fsize fnamefname
```

Literally

```
same   3492
same      4 C:\Users\me\go\pkg\mod\github.com\stamblerre\gocode@v1.0.0\internal\suggest\testdata\test.0063\test.go.inC:\Users\me\bin\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\usr\share\vim\vim81\syntax\vroom.vim
same   1004
same     52 C:\Users\me\go\pkg\mod\github.com\stamblerre\gocode@v1.0.0\internal\suggest\testdata\test.0062\test.go.inC:\Users\me\bin\cmder\vendor\git-for-windows\usr\share\vim\vim81\syntax\vsejcl.vim
```

What's going on? How can I fix it? Perhaps a threading issue?
-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a thread issue.

I removed the **`/MT:8`** and the log file looks fine.